# Number of paths in complete graph.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Lets consider complete graph $K_{4}$ and one of its vertices $a$. $A$ is adjacency matrix of $K_{4}$

The length of a path is a number of how many times we crossed some edge.

I call special path if it has length equal to $4$

> How many there are closed special paths including $a$ in $K_{4}$?

I am asking because i wrote by hand all the possibilities and i get $13$ but on the other hand using knowledge from link below all the values of a $A^{4}$ on main diagonal equal to $21$. A contradiction.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix

I am looking for someone who explain me how it schould work.

Comment: If the graph is complete, can't any permutation of the vertices be a closed special path? That would give an answer of $4!=24$.

Comment: @79037662 Can't it visit the same vertex more than once?

Comment: The most likely case is you probably just didn't actually write down all of the possibilities right?

Comment: @saulspatz Normally a "path" in a graph can't visit the same vertex twice by definition.

Comment: @79037662:  But if the path is closed maybe we don't care where it starts.  Then there are only $3!=6$

Comment: @79037662 I think don't think the terminology is standardized.  A lot of authors call that a "simple path".

Comment: @RossMillikan That's true but I assumed if OP counted 13 they probably did care where it starts.

Comment: @saulspatz Wikipedia says "most definitions" of path specify distinct vertices https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory). But you're right, it's not standard.

Comment: The paths included in the $21$ counted by the diagonal entries of $A^4$ include paths where the same edge is traversed more than once, even twice in succession.  You perhaps didn't count such paths.  In the Wiki article linked by $79037662$ these are called "walks."

Comment: No matter how creative I become, I don't get $13$. I think it's most likely you counted $12$ (a multiple of both $3$ and $4$) and overcounted once.

Answer (score 1):

Here's where the $21$ paths (or walks) come from.  You can compare to your work to see where the difference lies.  If we start at vertex $a$ and go to $b$, we can either proceed to a third vertex $c\neq a$ or we can return to $a$.  In the second case, the only way to get back to $a$ in two steps is to go to some vertex $d$ and then return to $a$.  We have $3$ choices for $b$ and $3$ for $d$, so there are $9$ paths of this type.

In the second case (where we have gone $a-b-c$) we again gave two choices: we can return to $b$ or we can go the the fourth vertex $d$.  In either case, we have then to return to $a$.  Reasoning as above, we see that there $6$ paths of each of these types, and $$9+6+6=21$$ paths in all.

Note that not all of these paths pass through every vertex, so we are only counting the closed walks of length $4$ that pass through $a$.